# Sorting list of objects using objects paramter of Long type

Tags: java, android, list

My post class contains following params

```
Post:
    String PostId
    Long imestamp

List<Post> posts;
```

I have a list of objects of type Post, how can I sort this list based on `Post.timestamp`. I tried comparator it asks for `int` type.

Comment: You can loop through your id's and use Long.compare(long x, long y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a `Comparator` like this:

```
Comparator<Post> comparator = new Comparator<Post>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Post o1, Post o2) {
        return Long.compare(o1.timestamp, o2.timestamp);
    }
};
```

Or let your `Post` implement `Comparable<Post>`:

```
class Post implements Comparable<Post> {
    String PostId;
    Long timestamp = 0;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Post post) {
        return Long.compare(this.timestamp, post.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @user8035311, i'll need to implement Comparator in  my Post class right?

Comment: @Dhirajkadam Yep, I added this to my answer as well.

Comment: Why not `return Long.compare(timestamp, post.timestamp);` in `compareTo(Post post)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda expresion and have it on one line

```
 Collections.sort(posts, Comparator.comparing(Post::timestamp));
```